# How to input list of number from users and output the numbers on console in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to input 10 integer from user and print the 10 integer in console in dart.
here is my code, but this is not working.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  List<int> arr = [0];

  print("Enter 10 number : ");

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.add(stdin.readByteSync());
  }
  print(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  var arr = <int>[];
  var i = 0;
  
  while (i < 10) {
    stdout.write('Enter #${i+1}: ');
    var x = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (x == null) continue;
    var n = int.tryParse(x);
    if (n == null) continue;
    arr.add(n);
    i++;
  }
  print('\nMy numbers: $arr');
}
```

Output:

```
Enter #1: 2
Enter #2: 43
Enter #3: er
Enter #3: 45
Enter #4: 7
Enter #5: 5
Enter #6: -3
Enter #7: ñ
Enter #7: 5
Enter #8: 6
Enter #9: 87
Enter #10: 2

My numbers: [2, 43, 45, 7, 5, -3, 5, 6, 87, 2]
```